# I dont find tBoostedFileInputXML in my palet

Tags: talend

I'm using Talend Open Studio for ESB (6.3.1), i need to use tBoostedFileInputXML but i dont find it in the palet, there is a plugin to add for having this component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard component, it seems you have to acquire it through the website of the developer. Then you can add the component in 'user component folder' to access it in the palette.

Comment: thanks for your answer, could you give me the link please ?

Comment: I need to parse a xml file of 5 GO, can i find a free component whose can do this ?